# Error with conector Google ADS GCP in AWS Appflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, amazon-appflow

I´m trying to create a flow in AWS to connect Google ADS.

I created connection Google ADS with id and secret from GCP and Google ads developer token, following this url:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/connectors-google-ads.html

But, when I try create flow and select this connection, show this error:

`Error while communicating to connector: The request failed because the service Source Google Ads returned the following error: Details: All available accounts are either in invalid state or developer token is not activated., ErrorCode: ResourceNotFoundError.`

I expect work well but show me error.